# Namespace not found error when compiling assembly from files

Tags: c#, entity-framework, namespaces, data-annotations, csharpcodeprovider

What I'm trying to achieve is generate a project dynamically from c# classes generated by me.
This classes' content are a similar content of code-first code generation of entity framework.The content looks as follows:

```
namespace ElasticTables
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute;

    [Table("address")]
    public partial class address
    {

        [Key]
        public decimal id { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I generate this files from the tables in my database, and then try to compile it programmatically so that I can reference the generated project in another project that works with an API.

The main errors while compiling is:

> The type or namespace name 'KeyAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace 'Key' could not be found
>
> The type or namespace 'Table' could not be found.

I'm using 'CSharpCodeProvider'

```
    var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    var options  = new CompilerParameters
    {
        OutputAssembly  = "ElasticTables.dll",
        CompilerOptions = "/optimize"
    };
```

And I have the following referenced Assemblies

```
options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\EntityFramework.dll");
options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll");
```

I have an string array with the files' paths called sources, and I try to compile with the following line

```
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(options, sources);
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: btw, in which directory is the assembly created? Do I specify it in the 'OutputAssembly' parameter? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference all needed assemblies (as the error says), so you need to add, I'd say at the very least:

```
options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll");
```

Others might be needed

About the comment in your question, yes, you should specify `options.OutputAssembly`

Also, in your generated code:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute;
```

`KeyAttribute` is not a namespace, so it'll probably give an error when compiling.

I'd also take the `usings` *before* the namespace. This is not strictly needed and not an error, but it's the common practice (and that way you are sure the referenced assemblies are from the `global` namespace, and not childs of the namespace your class is in [just in case there's a name conflict])

Comment: Your answer worked; I am not aware where does this assembly is positioned (its directory), is it perhaps located in the .net framework folder?

Comment: The referenced assemblies, unless you specify a full path, are looked for in the GAC (the `Global Assembly Cache`), typically `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_[32|64]`. You can read more about the GAC [on the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :).

Comment: @JosuéZatarain you'll find the most commonly used references if you open a default Visual Studio project template and look in the `References` folder in the solution explorer (including the `System` one that I put in the answer). You may want to see if you need any others :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add also a reference to "System.dll" and "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" (for the System.ComponentModel stuff) ?
(as you may indeed be missing an assembly reference)

```
options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(
    Path.Combine(
  Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
    "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll"));
```

Comment: Yeah, my answer is probably not pretty enough! :-)